# Why does TeX not like \usepackage?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

My prof writes papers with `harvmac`, which is apparently incompatible with LaTeX.  Fine, I switch to tex.  Now TeX gives me `Undefined control sequence` when I type `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

There's gotta be some equivalent to `\usepackage` (I've tried `\usepackage{amsmath.sty}` but it doesn't work).

Or maybe I'm completely hosed because `amsmath`/`harvmac` are fundamentally incompatible?

Comment: when trying to read about latex vs tex, I was googling 'latex vs ' and the auto completion suggested 'latex vs memory foam'. Naturally I thought that 'memory foam' was a new typesetting tools, that I just had not heard about before... I was disappointed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `\usepackage` macro is part of LaTeX, not part of plain TeX, and this is why you get an undefined control sequence error here. You will need to `\input` the appropriate files

```
\input amstex %
\input harvmac %
Some text here
$$ y = mx + c $$
\bye
```

Comment: Is amstex very different from amsmath?

Comment: @4tran AMSMath was derived from AMSTeX, although that was a long time ago and I don't know what the coverage of the two is now like. However, a bigger issue may be that plain TeX is not the same as LaTeX: for example, you'll notice that my example does not look like a standard LaTeX demo document.

Comment: I noticed that they're different - which is why I'm pulling my hairs out.

Apparently tex can't even handle empty lines inside of {} - gives me some crap about paragraph ending before expected grrr.

Comment: @4tran: That's exactly the same in LaTeX (which is of course based on TeX). If you have empty lines they are turned into a paragraph break, which is not allowed in normal, i.e. not-long, macros (defined with `\def` without preceding `\long`, or with `\newcommand*`).

Comment: @4tran -- when `amsmath` was developed based on ams-tex, the original syntax was modified only in the most "obvious" places, like changing `\align...\endalign` to \begin{align}...\end{align}.  however, since then, `amsmath` has been upgraded to use latex syntax for environments where ams-tex had one command with a (possibly complicated) argument.  as far as i know, there is no good free ams-tex documentation.  ask your professor to borrow his copy of *joy of tex* by michael spivak; that's the definitive manual.

Comment: In any case, a little bit of testing confirmed that amsmath is incompatible with harvmac; the former overrides something in the latter, regardless of which order I write the inputs @_@

Answer (score 8):

You can hardly expect something as fundamentally a part of LaTeX as `\usepackage` to continue working when you drop to plain TeX (apparently the "extended plain" format `eplain` brings some of it back).  Plain is a very minimal format and the only way to load "packages" is using `\input`; i.e. `\input harvmac`.  For the AMS package, you should try `\input amstex`.

Comment: The `\input` primitive does not use LaTeX `{...}` syntax: you want `\input harvmac`.

Comment: `eplain` supports loading *some* LaTeX packages with `\usepackage`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use [ams-tex](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/tex) but I have to admit, I'm not a TeXpert (don't use it).

```
\input amstex.tex

$a = b$.
\bye
```